# Find a value in a list loop, with blank spaces in between

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, one with data from a query (directly from database), DataSheet and one sheet with data that I copy in, DataCheck.
I want to check whether all data from DataCheck is in DataSheet.

DataSheet would be around 60.000 rows.
DataCheck is around 200 but is dynamic (sometimes 60, sometimes 800).
I can imagine doing a DO WHILE loop until an empty cell is reached.

DataCheck has some empty cells between data, and some cells with text that I don't have to check. The amount of rows with non-data is consistent. It'll always be two empty rows, 1 text row and then new data. I cannot delete these rows before putting them in.
I can imagine a third sheet where the data is copied to without the non-data.

Example:

| DATASHEET |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

| DATACHECK |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 9 |
|  |
|  |
| TEXT |
| 6 |

In this case, only the '9' would return as not present. It could be as easy as mark the 9 red in DATACHECK and give a msgbox saying 'not all data is present, please check'. Other way is to create a third sheet and pasting all the data that is not yet present.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a workaround eventually. First, I copy the entire worksheet to a new worksheet. Second, I delete all the empty rows and delete all the rows where there is text in the A column. That worked out :)

```
Sub Copy_Sheet()

Sheets("Blad3").Cells.Clear


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Blad2").Cells.Copy
Sheets("Blad3").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad3").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

Sub delete_empty_rows()

Sheets("Blad3").Select
Range("A2:A15000").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Sub Delete_Text_Rows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Blad3")
For iRow = ws.Range("A1:A999").rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Cells(iRow + 1, 1)) = True Then
ws.Cells(iRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next

End Sub
```